# Get-Hotfix showing updates are installed at 12.00 am but actually it is not

Tags: windows, powershell

I ran the below command in powershell. it is showing 12:00:00 AM as Installed time. but actually I pushed it at 3:00 AM. So how to get the actual time?

```
Get-Hotfix -ComputerName XXXX |
  Where-Object {$_.InstalledOn -eq '3/25/2016'} |
  Out-GridView
Security Update KB3126587   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 3/25/2016 0:00
Security Update KB3126593   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 3/25/2016 0:00
Security Update KB3127220   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 3/25/2016 0:00
Security Update KB3133043   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 3/25/2016 0:00
Security Update KB3135983   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 3/25/2016 0:00
Security Update KB3135988   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 3/25/2016 0:00
Update  KB3138612   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 3/25/2016 0:00
```

Comment: Look in Event Viewer

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the Windows update `.etl` files into a readable `.log` file by using the [Get-WindowsUpdateLog](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238376.aspx) cmdlet. Afterwards, parse the output file for lines where installation is invoked (by the Windows Update Agent, aka "[AGENT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/902093)" see the Components section):

`Get-WindowsUpdateLog`

`Get-Content .\WindowsUpdate.log | Select-String -pattern "Installing updates"`

Example output:

```
2016/04/02 03:10:10.7215463 1076  2872  Agent           *  START  *  Installing updates CallerId = WSAutoUpdate
2016/04/02 03:10:13.4877435 1076  2872  Agent           Installing updates CallerId = WSAutoUpdate
2016/04/04 21:23:26.7566600 1032  12660 Agent           *  START  *  Installing updates CallerId = WSAutoUpdate
2016/04/04 21:23:30.5200064 1032  12660 Agent           Installing updates CallerId = WSAutoUpdate
2016/04/07 15:06:47.3128367 1044  5864  Agent           *  START  *  Installing updates CallerId = WSAutoUpdate
2016/04/07 15:04:51.5237774 1044  5864  Agent           Installing updates CallerId = WSAutoUpdate
```

You may want to read [How to read the Windowsupdate.log file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/902093) and tune your search against the log to your needs, possibly by using [Select-String](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2010/05/06/select-string-context/)'s `-Context`.